# What kind of response is this obtained from EF Core 5 in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this method in my ASP.NET Core Web API Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Oferta>>> GetOfertas()
{
  return await _context.Ofertas.ToListAsync();
}
```

Then I have this method in my Angular App service

```
getOfertas(): Observable<Oferta[]> {
return this.http.get<Oferta[]>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/ofertas`)
  .pipe(
    tap(data=>console.log('OfertasService-get(): ', data)
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
```

}

And when I send a request like this to fill my table from my component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataService.getOfertas()
.pipe(
  tap(item=>console.log(item))
)
.subscribe(
  data=>{
    this.ofertas=data;
    this.ofertasOriginal=this.ofertas;
  }
)
,err=>console.log(err),
()=>{};


<div class='table-responsive'>
      <table class='table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Id Presentada</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th>Organismo</th>
            <th>Fª Presentación</th>
            <th>Presupuesto</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let oferta of ofertas.$values; let index=index">
            <td>{{oferta.id}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.idPresentada}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.descripcion}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.id}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum}}</td>
            <td>{{oferta.id}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I see nothing in it

[image: nothing]

I don't understand this kind of object returned

```
{
 $id:"1"
 $values:Array(16)
}
```

I expected only an array of Oferta objects

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: That's not ASP.NET Core at all, that's how Angular represents the data - the `Array(16)` tells you is on JavaScript side of things

Comment: Why we can't the content of `thead` ? Can you print F12 and check the element in your page.

Comment: My Web API returns only an array that Angular translates to an object with 2 properties: $id and $values where is my desired array. So in my *ngFor directive, I need to access that second property: let oferta of ofertas.$values but although in console I see the values in my table nothing is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i am getting the value from my web api in this way must be to avoid circular references

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
            x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After test, you should use something like `$.parseJSON(res)` to handle response data. In angular, maybe you can use `JSON.stringify(string_data)`;

*1. My test api and we can see response data on my side.*

[image]

*2. The response data is string format, not object. You can debugger in broswer to check.*

[image]

Comment: I need iterate an array not an string